# Why won't my date line up with my anchor tags under IE7,6?

Tags: html, css

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="#">test one<span>2011-06-21</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test one<span>2011-06-21</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test one<span>2011-06-21</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test one<span>2011-06-21</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test one<span>2011-06-21</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test one<span>2011-06-21</span></a></li>
      </ul>
```

the css:

```
ul {
    margin:15px 0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    line-height:28px;
}

ul li a {
    padding-left:20px;
    color:#2e2e2e;
    font-size:14px;
    text-shadow:#FFF 1px 1px;
    background: url(triangle.png) 0 5px no-repeat;
}

ul li a span {
    float:right;
}
```

Why won't my date line up with my right-floated anchor tags under IE 6 and 7, but is ok under firefox? How do I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you just need your spans on the left of the text preceeding it:

```
<a href="#"><span>2011-06-21</span>test one</a>
```

Comment: yeah,you're right. why changes the order. it can ok under IE?

Answer (score 0):

span is an inline element, meaning to do block-type floats on it, you must declare it as

```
span {
    display: block
}
```

Comment: Or just replace `<span>` with `<div>`, as a block level span is the same thing as a div.

Comment: Unless the span is specifically targeted by javascript for some reason, you're right, just switching to a div would be preferable.

Comment: i tried replace <span> with <div>, it's not with the text on the same line